# ¿Cómo puede acomodarlo dos widget dentro de Row por separado?

Tags: flutter, dart

Voy empezando en Flutter, he intentado realizar algo parecido dentro de un Row con children, lamentablemente no he tenido una respuesta buena.

[image: Ejemplo]

Lo he intentado de diferentes formas, les adjunto de la ultima forma que lo intente:

```dart
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: const [
                          Text("XXXXXX"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: const [
                          Text("ZZZZZ"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Me gustaría saber si me podrían asesorar de como hacerlo o algún ejemplo parecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo, es cuestión de conocer los widgets:

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text('Número'),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        '00007',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(
                thickness: 2,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: const [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text('Tipo'),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Factura C',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Divider(
                thickness: 2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo este link de referencia: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout

Flutter avanzado: [www.youtube.com/diegoveloper](http://www.youtube.com/diegoveloper)